# Why is disilyne bent?

Tags: vsepr-theory, molecular-structure

Why is disilyne $\ce{Si2H2}$ bent when the steric number of silicon is 2?
[image]

Comment: Short answer is: because VSEPR theory is oversimplified model of reality.

Comment: "The equilibrium geometry of disilyne is not linear, but is twisted. The potential surfaces of acetylene and disilyne have a critical internuclear distance between the central atoms, where the stable geometry changes from linear to twisted forms. The R-dependence of the valence-shell electron energy causes the difference in the structure of the molecules." dx.doi.org/10.1016/0009-2614(82)87044-9

Comment: Could you elaborate that in an answer? Why is that particular form more abundant than linear?

Comment: So electronic structure calculations cited above predict twisted equilibrium geometry for $\ce{H2Si2}$ with the only issue that the calculations are rather crude (HF/STO-3G). :D

Comment: Is there any intuitive explanation?

Comment: The twisted form of $\ce{H2Si2}$ is more energetically *stable*, and thus, it is more likely to find $\ce{H2Si2}$ in this form. The question why the twisted form is more stable does not have an answer you are looking for, except for that this is just the way nature works. :D It can be explained in terms of electronic structure theory as in the paper linked in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Nope. I doubt that there exist any "intuitive" explanation for this, where by intuitive you mean "without using electronic structure theory".

Comment: You can actually explain this in terms of a second-order Jahn-Teller distortion and associated correlation diagrams. Basically the HOMO becomes more lone-pair like.

Comment: Could you elaborate that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following disilyne has been prepared and found to be stable to ~100 C.  An X-ray crystal structure found that the two silicon atoms in the triple bond, Si(1) and Si(1'), along with the two attached silicon atoms, Si(2) and Si(2') are coplanar and the Si(1)-Si(1')-Si(2') angle is 137.44 degrees ("trans-bent").

[image]

The full text of the article describing the preparation, characterization and reactivity of the compound can be found [here](http://www.mycrandall.ca/faculty/MSchriver/coursewebs/BCSJ2006SiSi.pdf).  See figure 4 in the paper for a MO explanation as to why the trans-bent geometry occurs. Basically, the authors suggest that, "the bending is thought to be the result of the mixing of an in-plane $\ce{\pi}$-orbital with a $\ce{\sigma^{\ast}}$ orbital whose energies are close enough to cause the interaction."

Comment: Very interesting, but it's hard to imagine the overlap.

Comment: I was impressed by the fact (above link, Section 4, paragraph 2) that the bond length contraction going from $\ce{Si=Si}$ to $\ce{Si#Si}$ is half that for $\ce{C=C}$ to $\ce{C#C}$.  That seems significant to me.